# How to check if something COULD be a string in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements

I would like to create a TypeScript type which is checking if an element COULD be a string or not.

That means that this element could have the type "string" or "any", but not "number", "boolean", "number[]", "Person", etc.

I tried with conditional types, but I can't find how to exclude "all which is impossible to be a string".

I tried too the type Exclude<any, string>, but that's not exactly what I want.

**EDIT**

I explain better my problem : I create a static method `foo(data)` which will do something and return a `string` if data is a `string` or do something else and return a `number` if data is not a `string`.

For that, it's simple, I can do an overload like this:

```
class FooClass {

    static foo(data: string): string
    static foo(data: any): number
    static foo(data: any): string | number {
        if (typeof data === 'string') {
            return 'a';
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, assume that the `foo()` method will throw an Error if `data` is not a `string`. I have two cases :

- If the user of the method don't know the type of the data (which could be a `string`), I want that he can use this method and I will return an Error if it's not a `string`.
- If the user knows the type of the data (a `number`, for example), I want to tell him that it's impossible, it can't be a `string`. I want to tell that on type checking (error displayed in the IDE), not at runtime.

```
class FooClass {

    static foo(data: string): string
    static foo(data: NotAString): Error
    static foo(data: any): string | Error {
        if (typeof data === 'string') {
            return 'a';
        } else {
            return new Error();
        }
    }
}
let foo1: string;
const bar1: string = FooClass.foo(foo1);  // No error
let foo2: any;
const bar2: string = FooClass.foo(foo2);  // No error
let foo3: number;
const bar3: string = FooClass.foo(foo3);  // Error (displayed on the IDE)
let foo4: Bar;
const bar4: string = FooClass.foo(foo4);  // Error (displayed on the IDE)
```

I'd like to know how to define the type NotAString (or its contrary, CouldBeAString).

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: An element can be `any` but not "number", "boolean", "number[]", "Person", etc? Do you understand the meaning of `any`? Wwhat is "etc."? You need either a complete whitelist or a complete blacklist but it looks like you have neither. The whitelist "string" or "any" means that all types are allowed.

Comment: Why isn't 'string' enough? I don't understand the difference you are trying to achieve from your examples

Comment: Thanks for your first answers. I think that my question was not clear, because the responses are not doing exactly what I want.

I edited my post and added a concrete example of my problem, hoping it will be more clear.

And please, could you remove your -1 ? I think that now my question is correct and make sense. Thanks ! 

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be confusing the type system with functional checks here.

In case you need to check at runtime if something is a string, you would use the same logic as in normal JS.

**Runtime check on a property**

`if (typeof something === 'string') { ... }`

If we are talking about the data you get from an API or something like that, you would always need to use something like this, because type system will not do automatic runtime checks for you.

**Conditional type thinning**

In case you need to create a conditional type that allows you to do type thinning on a parameter there are a few ways to go about it. However, one thing to note here is the following:

- the `unknown` is the default type in current versions of TS, not `any`
- `unknown` and `any` means any valid data type in the language. You cannot say something is `unknown` but not `number` or `boolean`.
- If you don't know what something is use `unknown`
- If you know it is an object, but not sure  what props it has you can define it as `Record<string, unknown>`

For type thinning, you can use a combination of a generic property and extends keyword.

```
type Result<T> = T extends string
  ? A
  : T extends boolean
  ? B
  : T extends number
  ? C
  : never;
```

Where A, B, C are result types based on the generic type.

If a generic parameter is not explicitly set, the incoming prop is of `unknown` type by default. You can also scope it to a few values that your entry parameter can be in to have more granular control.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That's not exactly what I want to do, so I edited my post to be more clear. Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: I will gladly update the answer. Thanks for clearing up the confusion

Comment: I hadn't thought about using ternary in this way, to find a type, and I'm glad this answer is still up